# R using "extract" Function: all cases discarded after aggregation

Tags: r, function, extract

I'm trying to use the "extract" Function in R, which allows for Policy Mood analysis (documentation can be found here: http://www.unc.edu/~jstimson/Software_files/Doc.pdf). All of my cases are discarded, however, and I can't figure out whether the data or the function is the problem.

Here is a sample dataset with the code needed to execute the function (the "extract" function code is included further below):

```
library(car)
#create sample data frame
mat <- matrix(, nrow = 10, ncol = 0)
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
mat$year <- c(1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,1996,1997,1998,2000,2002) #survey years
mat$varname <- c("ESS","ESS","ESS","ESS","ESS","ISSP","ISSP","ISSP","ISSP","ISSP") #survey names
mat$index <- c(10,20,30,20,30,10,20,30,20,10) #approval rating in survey
mat$ncases <- c(1000,1120,1300,800,1000,1200,1300,1400,1100,1000) #number of survey respondents

source("Extract.r") #loading Extract for estimating Mood
mat$date<-ISOdate(mat$year,1,1) #generate date variable
output<-extract(mat$varname,mat$date,mat$index,mat$ncases) #estimate mood series
```

The final line returns the following:

```
[1] "Series ESS discarded.  After aggregation cases = 0"
[1] "Series ISSP discarded.  After aggregation cases = 0"
Error in issue[, v] : subscript out of bounds
```

So the surveys are all being eliminated as unusable at aggregation. My best guess, looking at the function code below, is that the cases are being dropped for having uncomputable or zero standard deviations - but I don't understand why that would be the case.

Finally, here is the Extract.r code for the function. The code chunk I believe may be causing problems begins at "#NOW REDUCE ISSUE MATRIX TO ELIMINATE UNUSABLE SERIES (WN<2)":

```
 display<-function(out,filename=NULL) {
   if (is.null(filename)) filename=""
   d<-out$dimensions
   p<-out$period
   m<-out$latent1
   if (d==2) m2<-out$latent2     
   T<-out$T
   mo=100*(p-as.integer(p))
   for (t in 1:T) {
     yr<-format(as.integer(p[t]),nsmall=0)
     month<-format(mo[t],digits=2)
     lat1<-format(m[t],nsmall=3)
     if (d==1) {
       cat(c(yr,month,lat1),fill=TRUE,file=filename,append=TRUE)
     } else {
       lat2<-format(m2[t],nsmall=3)
       cat(c(yr,month,lat1,lat2),fill=TRUE,file=filename,append=TRUE)
     }
   }
 }
##########################################################################################
plot.Zextract<-function(outobject) {
  dim<- outobject$dimensions
  T<- outobject$T
  vect1<-outobject$latent1
  t<-seq(1:T)
  if (dim>1) {
    vect2<-outobject$latent2
    miny<-min(vect1)
    if (miny>min(vect2)) miny<-min(vect2)
    maxy<-max(vect1)
    if (maxy<max(vect2)) maxy<-max(vect2)
    dummy<-rep(miny,T-1) #dummy is a fake variable used to reset axes to handle min/max of both series
    dummy[T]<-maxy
    leg.text<-c("","Dimension 1","Dimension 2")
    plot(t,dummy,type="l",lty=0,main="Final Estimation Results: Two Dimensions",xlab="Time Point",ylab="Latent Variables")
    lines(t,vect1,col=1)
    lines(t,vect2,col=2)
    legend(1,maxy,leg.text,col=c(0,1,2),lty=c(0,1,1))
  } else {
    plot(t,vect1,type="l",main="Final Estimation Results",xlab="Time Point",ylab="Latent Variable")
    if (dim == 2) lines(t,vect2,col=2)
    }
  }
##########################################################################################
summary.Zextract<- function(outobject) {
  T=outobject$T
  nvar=outobject$nvar
  dim<- outobject$dimensions
  vn<- c(outobject$varname,"Variable Name")
  vn<- format(vn,justify="right")
  nc<- format(outobject$N,justify="right")
  ld<- format(outobject$loadings1,digits=3,justify="right")
  mean<- format(outobject$means,digits=6,justify="right")
  sd<- format(outobject$std.deviations,digits=6,justify="right")
  cat("Variable Loadings and Descriptive Information: Dimension 1\n")
  cat(paste(vn[nvar+1],"Cases","Loading","   Mean ","Std Dev","\n"))
  for (v in 1:nvar) {
    cat(paste(vn[v],"  ",nc[v]," ",ld[v],mean[v],sd[v],"\n"))
    }
  if (dim == 2) {
    ld<- format(outobject$loadings2,digits=3,justify="right")
    cat("\nVariable Loadings and Descriptive Information: Dimension 2\n")
    cat(paste(vn[nvar+1],"Cases","Loading","   Mean ","Std Dev","\n"))
    for (v in 1:nvar) {
      cat(paste(vn[v],"  ",nc[v]," ",ld[v],mean[v],sd[v],"\n"))
    }
  }
}
##########################################################################################
findper<-function(unit,curdate,mind,miny,minper,aggratio) { #returns intFindPer
  datcurdate<-curdate
  class(datcurdate)<-"Date"
  mo <- findmonth(datcurdate)
  qu <- 1 + as.integer((mo - 1)/3)
  dy <- findday(datcurdate)
  yr <- findyear(datcurdate)
  arinv<- 1/aggratio
  if (unit == "D") intFindPer <- curdate - mind +1 #curdate - mindate + 1
  if (unit == "A" || unit == "O") intFindPer <- as.integer((yr - miny) / aggratio) + 1
  if (unit == "Q") part <- qu
  if (unit == "M") part <- mo
  if (unit == "Q" || unit == "M") intFindPer <- (yr - miny - 1) * arinv + part + (arinv - (minper - 1))
  return(intFindPer)
  } #findper
##########################################################################################
findday<-function(DateVar) {
  z<-as.POSIXlt(DateVar)
  v<-unlist(z)
  findday<-as.integer(v[4])
  } #end findday
##########################################################################################
findmonth<-function(DateVar) {
  z<-as.POSIXlt(DateVar)
  v<-unlist(z)
  findmonth<-as.integer(v[5])+1
  } #end findmonth
##########################################################################################
findyear<-function(DateVar) {
  z<-as.POSIXlt(DateVar)
  v<-unlist(z)
  findyear<-as.integer(v[6])+1900
  } #end findyear
##########################################################################################
aggregate<- function(varname,date,index,ncases,mindate,maxdate,nperiods,nvar,aggratio,unit,miny,minper) {   #
    #READ A NEW RECORD, CALCULATE PERIOD, AND SET UP AGGREGATION INTO MAT.ISSUE[NPERIODS,NVAR] 
  vl<- character(nvar)
  mind<- as.integer(mindate)/86400
  maxd<- as.integer(maxdate)/86400
  vfac<- factor(varname) #make a factor vector
  vlev<- levels(vfac)    #find unique categories
  Mat.Issue<- array(dim=c(nperiods,nvar))

  nrec<-length(varname) #added for R compatibility
  lp<- 0
  per<- 0
  x<- 0
  c<- 0
  nkeep<- 0
  lv<- "0"
  for (record in 1:nrec) { # MASTER LOOP THROUGH INPUT DATA, 1 TO NREC
    if (ncases[record] == 0 || is.na(ncases[record])) ncases[record] <- 1000
    mo <- findmonth(date[record])
    qu <- 1 + as.integer((mo - 1)/3)
    dy <- findday(date[record])
    yr <- findyear(date[record])
    curdate<- as.integer(date[record])
    if (curdate >= mind &&  curdate <= maxd) {  #is date within range?
    nkeep <- nkeep + 1
    if (nkeep==1) { #startup routine for first good case
      firstcase<- TRUE
      lp <- findper(unit,curdate,mind,miny,minper,aggratio)
      lv <- varname[record]
      x <- index[record] * ncases[record] #start new sums for case 1
      c <- ncases[record]
      for (i in 1:nvar) {
        if (lv==vlev[i]) v=i #determine v by matching to position of labels vector
        } #end for
      } else {
      firstcase<- FALSE
      } #end if
    if (firstcase == FALSE) { #skip over the rest for first good case
    per<- findper(unit,curdate,mind,miny,minper,aggratio) #here we translate date into agg category
    if ((varname[record] !=  lv) || (per !=lp)) { #found a new period or variable name
      if (lp > 0 &&  lp <= nperiods) {
        Mat.Issue[lp, v] <- x / c #recompute for either period or var change
        x<- 0
        c<- 0
        }
      if (varname[record] !=  lv) { #new var only
        for (i in 1:nvar) {
          if (varname[record]==vlev[i]) v=i #determine v by matching to position of labels vector
          } #end for
        vl[v]<- varname[record] #this will only catch names that have good cases
        lv<-vl[v]  #reassign new varname to lastvar
      } # new var
      lp <- findper(unit,curdate,mind,miny,minper,aggratio)
      x <- index[record] * ncases[record] #start new sums for current case
      c <- ncases[record]
    } else {
      x<- x + index[record] * ncases[record] #a continuing case, increment sums
      c<- c + ncases[record]
    }
    } # end of first case special loop
  } #end of date test loop
  } #newrec: next record
  vl<- vlev #overwrite previous assignment which had good names only
  agglist<- list(lab=vl,iss=Mat.Issue)
  return(agglist) #list includes labels and issue matrix
  } #end aggregate function
##########################################################################################

esmooth<- function(mood, fb, alpha){ 
##########################################################################################
smooth<- function(alpha) { #for time series "series" and alpha "alpha[1]" compute sum of squared forecast error
ferror<- numeric(1)
T<- length(series)
xvect<- numeric(T)        
xvect[1] <-  series[1]
for (t in 2:T) { 
  xvect[t] <-  alpha[1] * series[t] + (1 - alpha[1]) * xvect[t - 1]
}
sumsq <-  0
for (t in 3:T) { 
  ferror <-  series[t] - xvect[t - 1]
  sumsq <-  sumsq + ferror ^ 2
} 
return(sumsq) #this is the value of the function for a particular parameter alpha[1]
} # END OF FUNCTION SMOOTH   
##########################################################################################

series<- mood[fb,] #create series to be smoothed
sm.out<- optim(c(.75),smooth,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=0.5,upper=1)  #call smoother
alpha<- sm.out$par                          #assign result to alpha
#NOW SMOOTH USING ALPHA
T<- length(series)
for (t in 2:T) { 
  mood[fb,t] <-  alpha * series[t] + (1 - alpha) * mood[fb,t - 1]
}
return(alpha)
} #END OF FUNCTION ESMOOTH
##########################################################################################
residmi<- function(issue,v,mood) { #function regresses issue(v) on mood and then residualizes it
o<- lm(issue[,v] ~ mood[3,]) #regress issue on mood to get a,b
issue[,v]<- 100 + issue[,v] - (o$coef[1]+o$coef[2]*mood[3,]) #100 + Y - (a+bx)
return(issue[,v])
} 
##########################################################################################
iscorr<- function(issue,mood) { #compute issue-scale correlations
  Nv<- length(issue[1,])
  Np<- length(issue[,1])
  Rvector<- numeric(Nv)
  for (v in 1:Nv) {
    N<- Np - sum(is.na(issue[,v]))
    if (N > 1) Rvector[v]<- cor(issue[,v],mood[3,],use="complete.obs",method="pearson")
    }
  return(Rvector)
  } #end function iscorr
##########################################################################################
dominate<- function(fb,issue,nperiods,nvar,mood,valid,smoothing,alpha) {
nitems<- numeric(nperiods)
if (fb==2) alpha1<-alpha
if (fb==1) {
  unexp<-numeric(1)
  everlap<- integer(1)
  alpha<- 1
  alpha1<- 1
  } 

  if (fb == 1) {
    startper <- 1
    mood[fb, startper] <- 100
    firstj <- 2
    lastj <- nperiods
    stepj <- 1
    jprev <- 1
  } else {
    startper <- nperiods
    mood[fb, startper] <- mood[1, nperiods] #reuse forward metric
    firstj <- nperiods - 1
    lastj <- 1
    stepj <- -1
    jprev <- nperiods
  } #    end if
for (j in seq(firstj,lastj,by=stepj)) {  
  mood[fb, j] <- 0
  everlap <- 0 ## of years which have contributed sums to mood
  if (fb == 1) {
    firstj2 <- 1
    lastj2 <- j - 1
  } else  {
    firstj2 <- j + 1
    lastj2 <- nperiods
  } # end if

  for (j2 in firstj2:lastj2) { 
    sum <- 0     #has already been estimated
    consum <- 0  #sum of communalities across issues
    overlap <- 0
    for (v in 1:nvar) { 
      xj <- issue[j, v]                      #xj is base year value
      sngx2 <- issue[j2, v]                  #sngx2 is comparison year value
      if (!is.na(xj) && !is.na(sngx2)) {  
        overlap <- overlap + 1               #numb of issues contributing to sum
        ratio <- xj / sngx2
        if (csign[v] < 0)  ratio <- 1 / ratio
        sum <- sum + valid[v] * ratio * mood[fb, j2] 
        consum <- consum + valid[v]
      } #              end if
    } #next v
    if (overlap > 0) {
      everlap <- everlap + 1
      mood[fb, j] <- mood[fb, j] + sum / consum
    } # end if
  } #next j2
  nitems[j] <- everlap
  if (everlap > 0) mood[fb, j] <- mood[fb, j] / everlap else mood[fb, j] <- mood[fb, jprev] #if undefined, set to lag(mood)
  jprev <- j #last value of j, whether lead or lag
} #next j
  if (smoothing == TRUE) {
    alpha<- esmooth(mood, fb, alpha)     #NOW SMOOTH USING ALPHA
    mood.sm<- mood[fb,] #set up alternate vector mood.sm
    for (t in 2:nperiods) { 
      mood.sm[t]<- alpha*mood[fb,t]+(1-alpha)*mood.sm[t-1]
    } #end for
    mood[fb,]<- mood.sm #now assign back smoothed version
  } else {
    alpha1 <- 1
    alpha <- 1
  } 
  if (smoothing == TRUE && fb == 1) alpha1 <- alpha
dominate.out<- list(alpha1=alpha1,alpha=alpha,latent=mood[fb,]) #output object
return(dominate.out)  
#  return(mood[fb,])
} #end dominate algorithm  
##########################################################################################





#begindt<-NA #ISOdate(2004,6,1)
#enddt<-NA #ISOdate(2004,10,31)

##########################################################################################
## MAIN EXTRACT CODE BEGINS HERE #########################################################
extract<- function(varname,date,index,ncases=NULL,unit="A",mult=1,begindt=NA,enddt=NA,npass=1,smoothing=TRUE,endmonth=12) {
  formula<-match.call(extract)
  nrecords<- length(varname)
  if (is.null(ncases)) ncases<- rep(0,nrecords)
  moddate<- date #create temporary date vector, leaving original unmodified
  if ((unit=="A" || unit=="O") && endmonth<12) {
    for (i in 1:nrecords) { #first loop through raw data file
      month<- findmonth(moddate[i])
      year<- findyear(moddate[i])
      if (month>endmonth) moddate[i]<- ISOdate(year+1,1,1) #modified date become 1/1 of next year
    } #end loop through data
  } # end if

  if (is.na(begindt)) minper<-findmonth(min(moddate)) else minper<-findmonth(begindt)
  if (is.na(begindt)) miny<-findyear(min(moddate)) else miny<-findyear(begindt)
  if (is.na(begindt)) minday<-findday(min(moddate)) else minday<-findday(begindt)
  if (is.na(enddt)) maxper<-findmonth(max(moddate)) else maxper<-findmonth(enddt)
  if (is.na(enddt)) maxy<-findyear(max(moddate)) else maxy<-findyear(enddt)
  if (is.na(enddt)) maxday<-findday(max(moddate)) else maxday<-findday(enddt)
  if (unit=="Q") {
    minper<- as.integer((minper-1)/3)+1
    maxper<- as.integer((maxper-1)/3)+1
  }
  mindate<- ISOdate(miny,minper,minday,0,0,0,tz="GMT")
  maxdate<- ISOdate(maxy, maxper, maxday,0,0,0,tz="GMT") #86400=24*60*60

  #SETCONS:
  latent<- numeric(1)
  aggratio<- 0
  fb<- 1 #initialize
  auto<- "start"  #meaningless value
  alpha<- 1
  alpha1<- 1
  pass<- 1
  holdtola<- 0.001
  tola<- holdtola
  iter<- 0
  lastconv<- 99999
  wtmean<- 0 #for it=1
  wtstd<- 1
  fract<- 1

  if (unit=="A") {
    nperiods<- maxy-miny+1
    aggratio<- 1
    months<- 12
  }
  if (unit=="O") {
    years<- mult
    months<- years*12
    aggratio<- 2
    odd<- (maxy-miny+1) %% mult  #mod
    nperiods=as.integer((maxy-miny)/mult) + odd
  }
  if (unit=="M") {
    fract<- 100
    nperiods<- (maxy-miny)*12
    nperiods<- nperiods-12 + (12-minper+1) + maxper
    aggratio<- 1/12
    months<- 1
  }
  if (unit=="Q") {
    aggratio<- 1/4
    months<- 3
    nperiods<- as.integer((maxy-miny)/aggratio)
    nperiods<- nperiods-4 + (4-minper+1) + maxper
    fract<- 10
  }
  if (unit=="D") {
    months=1
    nperiods<- (as.integer(maxdate)-as.integer(mindate))/86400 + 1 #86400=24*60*60
  }

  arinv<- 1/aggratio
  aggratio<- months/12
  nrecords<- length(index)

#HERE WE SET UP FUNDAMENTAL DIMENSIONS AND DECLARE VECTORS
  if (fb != 2)  mood<- array(dim=c(3,nperiods))
  vfac<- factor(varname) #make a factor vector
  vlev<- levels(vfac)    #find unique categories
  nvar<- length(vlev)    #how many are there?, includes unusable series
  valid<- numeric(nvar)
  csign<<- numeric(nvar)
  vl<- character(nvar)
  r<- numeric(nvar)
  oldr<- rep(1,nvar) # r=1 for all v initially

  issue<- array(dim=c(nperiods,nvar))
  count<- numeric(nperiods)
  vl<- numeric(nvar)
  period<- numeric(nperiods)
  converge<- 0
  evalue<- 0

  # create numeric variable period, eg, yyyy.0m 
  if (unit=="D") {
    period<-seq(1:nperiods) 
    } else {
  if (months >= 12) {
    for (l in 1:nperiods) { 
      p <- (l - 1) * aggratio
      period[l] <- miny + p
      } #next l
   } else {
     y <- 0
     i <- 0
     my <- miny
     if (minper == 1)  my <- my - 1
     for (l in 1:nperiods) { 
       i<- 1 + ((l-1) %% arinv)
       mq <- minper + i - 1
       mq<- 1 + ((mq-1) %% arinv) 
       if (mq == 1)  y <- y + 1 #first month or quarter, increment year
       period[l] <- my + y + mq / fract
     } # end for
   } #end else
  } # end if


  agglist<- aggregate(varname,moddate,index,ncases,mindate,maxdate,nperiods,nvar,aggratio,unit,miny,minper) # call aggregate to produce issue matrix
  vl<- agglist$lab #extract two elements of the list from aggregate call
  issue<- agglist$iss
  rm(agglist) #don't need this anymore

  #NOW REDUCE ISSUE MATRIX TO ELIMINATE UNUSABLE SERIES (WN<2)
  ndrop<- 0
  nissue<- numeric(nperiods)
  std<- numeric(nperiods)
  for (v in 1:nvar) {
    std[v]<- 0 #default
    nissue[v]<- sum(!is.na(issue[,v])) #criterion is 2 cases for npass=1 or 3 for npass=2
    if (nissue[v]>npass) std[v]<- sqrt(var(issue[,v],na.rm=TRUE)) #this is just a test for variance >0
    if (std[v]<.001) {  #case dropped if std uncomputable (NA) or actually zero (constant)
      ndrop<- ndrop+1
      print(paste("Series",vl[v],"discarded.  After aggregation cases =",nissue[v]))
      }
    }
  nvarold<- nvar
  nvar<- nvar-ndrop
  pointer<- 1
  found<- FALSE

  for (v in 1:nvar) { #now reduced nvar
    while (found==FALSE && pointer<=nvarold) { #find first valid column and push down
      if (std[pointer]>.001) { #good case, transfer
         issue[,v]<- issue[,pointer]
         vl[v]<- vl[pointer]
         pointer<- pointer+1
         found<- TRUE
      } else {
        pointer<- pointer+1 #bad case, increment pointer
      } #end if
    } #end while
    found<- FALSE
  } #for
  length(vl)<- nvar #reduce  
  length(issue)<- nperiods*nvar  #chop off unused columns
  attr(issue,"dim")<- c(nperiods,nvar)
  N<- numeric(nvar)

#export<<-list(nperiods,nvar,issue)


  for (pass in 1:npass) { #newpass: RESTART FOR SECOND DIMENSION CASE
    if (pass == 2) { #reset iteration control parameters
      iter <- 0
      tola = holdtola
      lastconv <- 99999
      converge<- lastconv
      conv<- converge
    } else {
      av<- numeric(nvar)
      std<- numeric(nvar)
#      ngood<- 0
      for (v in 1:nvar) { #compute av and std by issue nvar now reduced to good cases
        wn<- as.integer(nperiods-sum(is.na(issue[,v])))
        av[v] <- mean(issue[,v],na.rm=TRUE)
        std[v]<- sqrt(var(issue[,v],na.rm=TRUE) * ((wn - 1)/wn)) #convert to population standard deviation
        issue[,v]<- 100 + 10 * (issue[,v] - av[v])/std[v]  #standardize
#        ngood<- ngood+1
      }#end for
    }
    #READY FOR ESTIMATION, SET UP AND PRINT OPTIONS INFO     
    out<- as.character(10) #initial length only
    out[1]<- print(paste("Estimation report:"))
    if (pass == 1) {
      if (months >= 12) {
        out[2]<- print(paste("Period:", miny, " to", maxy,"     ", nperiods, " time points"))
      } else {
        out[2]<- print(paste("Period:", miny,  minper, " to", maxy, maxper, nperiods, " time points"))
      }
      out[3]<- print(paste("Number of series: ", nvar+ndrop))
      out[4]<- print(paste("Number of usable series: ", nvar))
      out[5]<- print(paste("Exponential smoothing: ",smoothing))
    }
    out[6]<- print(paste("Iteration history: Dimension ",pass))
    print(" ")
    out[7]<- print("Iter Convergence Criterion Reliability Alphaf Alphab")
    outcount<- 7

    for (p in 1:nperiods) {
      count[p]<- sum(!is.na(issue[p,]))
    }
    valid<- rep(1,times=nvar)
    csign<<- rep(1,times=nvar)
    auto <- "y"              #iterative estimation on by default
    quit <- 0                #false implies go ahead and estimate

    while (iter == 0 || converge > tola) {   #MASTER CONTROL LOOP WHICH ITERATES UNTIL SOLUTION REACHED

      for (fb in 1:2) { #    MASTER fb LOOP       fb=1 is forward, 2 backward 
        dominate.out<- dominate(fb,issue,nperiods,nvar,mood,valid,smoothing,alpha)  #master estimation routine
        alpha1<- dominate.out$alpha1
        alpha<- dominate.out$alpha
        mood[fb,]<- dominate.out$latent
        } #next fb

    fb <- 3 #average mood from here on
    for (p in 1:nperiods) { #    AVERAGE
      mood[fb, p] <- (mood[1, p] + mood[2, p]) / 2
    } #next p
    moodmean<-mean(mood[3,])
    sdmood<-sd(mood[3,])
    for (p in 1:nperiods) {  #PLACEMENT OF THIS LOOP MAY NOT BE RIGHT
      mood[fb,p] <- ((mood[fb,p] - moodmean) * wtstd / sdmood) + wtmean
    } #end for

    #plot commands
    t<- seq(1:nperiods) #time counter used for plot below
    lo<- 50 #force scale of iterative plot to large range
    hi<- 150
    if (min(mood[3,]) < lo) lo=min(mood[3,]) #whichever larger, use
    if (max(mood[3,]) > hi) hi=max(mood[3,])
    dummy<- rep(lo,nperiods) #dummy is fake variable used to set plot y axis to 50,150
    dummy[nperiods]<- hi
    if (iter==0) {
      plot(t,dummy,type="l",lty=0,xlab="Time Period",ylab="Estimate by iteration",main="Estimated Latent Dimension") #create box, no visible lines
      } else {
      lines(t,mood[3,],col=iter)
    }  

    iter <- iter + 1 
    if (auto == "y") r<- iscorr(issue,mood) else auto <- "y"   #recompute correlations

    wtmean<- 0
    wtstd<- 0
    vsum<- 0
    goodvar<- 0
    converge<- 0 #start off default
    evalue<- 0
    totalvar<- 0

    for (v in 1:nvar) {
      wn<- nperiods-sum(is.na(issue[,v]))
      if (!is.na(sign(r[v]))) csign[v]<<- sign(r[v])
      wn<- nperiods-sum(is.na(issue[,v]))
      if (wn>1) { #sum over variables actually used
        vratio <- wn / nperiods
        evalue <- evalue + vratio * r[v]^2
        totalvar <- totalvar + vratio
      } #end if

      #convergence tests
      if (wn > 3) {
       conv <- abs(r[v] - oldr[v])      #conv is convergence test for item=v
       conv <- conv * (wn / nperiods)                #weight criterion by number of available periods
       if (conv > converge)  converge <- conv        #converge is the global max of conv
      } #end if
      if (!is.na(r[v])) oldr[v] <- r[v]
      if (!is.na(r[v])) valid[v] <- r[v]^2
      if (!is.na(av[v])) wtmean <- wtmean + av[v] * valid[v]
      if (!is.na(std[v])) wtstd <- wtstd + std[v] * valid[v]
      if (!is.na(r[v])) vsum <- vsum + valid[v]
    } #end v loop

    if (vsum > 0)  wtmean <- wtmean / vsum
    if (vsum > 0)  wtstd <- wtstd / vsum
    if (pass == 1) {
      mean1 <- wtmean
      std1 <- wtstd
      e1=evalue
    } else {
      wtmean <- mean1
      wtstd <- std1 #*unexp
    } #end if
    fbcorr <- cor(mood[1,],mood[2,]) #fnfrontback 

    if (quit != 1) {
      outcount<- outcount+1
      cv<- format(round(converge,4),nsmall=4) 
      itfmt<-format(round(iter),justify="right",length=4)
      out[outcount]<- print(paste(itfmt,"       ",cv,"   ",round(tola,4),"    ",round(fbcorr,3),round(alpha1,4),round(alpha,4)))
      }
    if (converge > lastconv)  tola <- tola * 2
    lastconv <- converge

    auto = "y"  #skip corr on iter=1, set auto on

    if (iter >= 50) break #get out of while loop
    } #END MASTER WHILE ITERATION CONTROL LOOP

    if (auto == "y" && converge<tola) { #IF WE REACH THIS CODE WE HAVE A FINAL SOLUTION TO BE REPORTED
    if (pass == 1) out1<- out #hold output for 2 dimensional solution
    auto <- "Q"
    quit <- 1                #flag solution reached, last time through
    r<- iscorr(issue,mood)   #final iteration correlations
    if (pass == 1) r1<- r #hold correlations for 2 dimensional solution

    if (pass > 1) {
      unexp <- totalvar 
      totalvar <- unexp * totalvar
      evalue <- evalue * unexp
    } #    end if

    if (pass == 1) {
      expprop <- evalue / totalvar
      tot1 <- totalvar
    } else {
      erel <- evalue / totalvar          #% exp relative
      totalvar <- (1 - expprop) * tot1   #true var=original var discounted by %exp
      evalue <- erel * totalvar          #rescale to retain %exp relationship
      expprop <- evalue / tot1           #now reduce eral to expprop
    } #    end if

    for (v in 1:nvar) {
      N[v]<- sum(!is.na(issue[,v]))
      }
    var.out<- list(varname=vl,loadings=r,means=av,std.deviations=std)

    print(" ")  
    outcount<- outcount+1
    out[outcount]<- print(paste("Eigen Estimate ", round(evalue,2), " of possible ",round(tot1,2)))  
    outcount<- outcount+1
    out[outcount]<- print(paste("  Percent Variance Explained: ",round(100 * expprop,2)))

    if (pass !=  2 && npass>1) {
      for (v in 1:nvar) { 
        valid[v] <- 0               #reset all, regmoodissue will set good=1
        if (csign[v] != 0)  issue[,v]<- residmi(issue,v,mood)   #regmoodissue()
       } #v loop
    }  # if
    #begin prn output routine # mood[fb,] is now our estimate,    WHAT ABOUT A SECOND DIMENSION
    latent<- mood[fb,] #vector holds values for output
    if (pass == 1) latent1<- latent #hold first dimension
    print(" ")
    out[outcount+1]<- print(paste("Final Weighted Average Metric:  Mean: ",round(wtmean,2)," St. Dev: ",round(wtstd,2)))
    #for Zelig output
    if (npass==1) {
      extract.out<- list(formula=formula,T=nperiods,nvar=nvar,unit=unit,dimensions=npass,period=period,varname=vl,N=N,means=av,std.deviations=std,setup1=out1,loadings1=r1,latent1=latent1)
    } else {
    for (i in 6:outcount) {
      out[i-5]=out[i]
    }
    length(out)<- outcount-5
    extract.out<- list(formula=formula,T=nperiods,nvar=nvar,unit=unit,dimensions=npass,period=period,varname=vl,N=N,means=av,std.deviations=std,setup1=out1,loadings1=r1,latent1=latent1,setup2=out,loadings2=r,latent2=latent)
    }
    } #end if auto="y" 
  } #end of for pass=1,2 loop 

  par(col=1) #reset on termination
  class(extract.out)<- "Zextract"
  return(extract.out)
  } #end of extract
```

Anyone have any ideas what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be dates inside the `aggregate` function (note, not the base R `aggregate`). Namely, a minimum and maximum date are calculated as:

```
mind<- as.integer(mindate)/86400
maxd<- as.integer(maxdate)/86400
```

These are then compared (inside a loop for each date) against the `curdate` variable, using an `if` statement:

```
if (curdate >= mind &&  curdate <= maxd) {  #is date within range?
```

The problem, though, is that `curdate<- as.integer(date[record])` (the line immediately before the `if` statement) is not on the same time scale. Changing it to: `curdate<- as.integer(date[record])/86400` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solved me hours of hand-wringing, too.